# Ionic: Customize searchbar cancel-icon color

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I am aware that I can change the color of the clear-icon and the search-icon as follows:

```
$searchbar-md-input-clear-icon-color: white;
$searchbar-md-input-search-icon-color: white;
```

For the cancel-icon, however, this method does not seem to work.

```
$searchbar-md-input-cancel-icon-color: white;
```

The code above has no visible effect on the cancel-icon. Instead, the color of the cancel-icon always falls back to the defined primary color.

```
$colors: (
    primary: blue
);
```

How can I change the color of the cancel-icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `searchbar-md-input-cancel-icon-color` is not a property of [SearchBar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) component.

You need to sets style by a specific css selector like this :

```
.searchbar-ios-danger .searchbar-ios-cancel {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: This works for me removing the `.searchbar-ios-danger`!